# Configure same VLAN on cisco router for two ports

Tags: router, lan, cisco, subnet, vlan

I have to complete a part of a virtual network assignment.
The tasks sounds like "The VLan1 of the Sw3 should be assigned the second possible address of the subnet and fa0/1 of the R2 should be assigned the first possible address"

[image: Schema of the task]

The fa0/1 interface address was assigned successfully.
The problem is Sw3 is recognized as Router so I am not sure how I should configure vlans, I think it should be something with the encapsulation dot1q

[image: Sw3 as router]

If I try to assign the same ip for the e0/0.1 and e0/1.1 interfaces of the Sw3 I get the exception about overlapping ip's.

The subnet is 172.16.3.0/24 and I should be able to ping the Linux server with the ip 172.16.3.254 from both Sw3 and R2

Boot image for the Sw3 is l3-advipservices-m-15.4-2T.bin

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @rkpsegi ohh i didn't know it existed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Closing the question and moving it to networkengineering stackexchange